# Perform multiple Async operations in View Model and update View using MVVM

Tags: android, asynchronous, mvvm, kotlin, android-viewmodel

let assume that we have an Activity with 3 hidden buttons, and it has a viewModel which have 3 different operations done in the background. For every operation when it has done it sends a signal to the View to show it's button.

> Activity

```
class MyActivity  : BaseAppCompatActivity()  {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

    //this method called by onCreate
    override fun initViews(binding: ViewDataBinding) {
        viewModel = ViewMode()
    }

    fun WhenEventAHappens() {
        viewModel.performA()
    }

    fun WhenEventBHappens() {
        viewModel.performB()
    }

    fun WhenEventCHappens() {
        viewModel.performC()
    }
}
```

> ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel  : BaseViewModel()  {

    fun performA(){
            //Do some staff
            //Update UI : Show button A
        }

    fun performB(){
            //Do some staff
            //Update UI : Show button B
        }

    fun performC(){
            //Do some staff
            //Update UI : Show button C
        }
}
```

My question is, I'm sending 3 different signals from ViewModel for View, the call of those signals will not overlaps each other . what is the best solution?

> Single Observable with parameters?
>
> Multiple Observable, one for every operation?
>
> Others ?

Additional information: the Async tasks are done in the background and all the updates are done in the Main thread, my questions are not about threading ,  it's all about the observers

Comment: If you run the tasks in your view-model async then you should use something like `runOnUiThread` in your activity to update the UI and since there is only 1 UI thread the different callbacks won't interfere with each-other.

I don't know how you run your async code (tasks, RX Java etc); so hard to give you an answer of how you should handle the result of the tasks.

Comment: @Dires maybe my question wasn't clear enough, I just added additional information at the end